# CCNET Dashboard not working

Tags: powershell

I have installed CCNET and I am running some powershellscripts with it. It works fine, but the Dashboard does not show up. As I understood it, it is allready included in the basic installation of CCNET and does not need any other installation. But when I run localhost/ccnet the browser tells me that the page cannot be displayed.

Where is the dashboard running and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is a site to ask about programming related questions.

Comment: This is a programming related question. CCNET (Cruise Control .NET) is a continuous integration server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are hosting this on a machine running IIS, you need to create a Virtual Directory that points to the webdashboard folder in your install directory. See [here](http://www.matthewbussa.com/2011/05/installing-and-configuring-cruise.html) for additional information.

If you are using IIS7+, you will need to change lines 17 and 19 in the httpHandlers section to include the **preCondition="integratedMode"** attribute as follows.

```
<add verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="*.aspx" type="ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.ASPNET.HttpHandler,ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard"

<add verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="*.xml" type="ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.ASPNET.HttpHandler,ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard"
```

Comment: OK, i finally created a virtual directory that points to the dashboard. But unfortunately it still does not work :/ I get a http 500.0 error "asp.net initialization failed" The physical Path is correct :/

Comment: That sounds like IIS is having problems initializing the ASP.NET engine itself. I would need to see the whole error message to diagnose it further.

Comment: Hi, i only have the german output, and it does not fit in here. Can i mail it? :/
Modul    AspNetAppInitializationFailureModule 
Benachrichtigung    BeginRequest 
Handler    ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0 
Fehlercode    0x00000000 
Angeforderte URL    http://localhost:8080/ccnet 
Physischer Pfad    C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard 
Anmeldemethode    Noch unbestimmt 
Angemeldeter Benutzer    Noch unbestimmt 
Verzeichnis für Ablaufverfolgung    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\CCNET 
 Weitere Informationen:
Microsoft Knowledge Base-Artikel:

294807

Comment: Ah, I think I might know what that is. If you are running on IIS 7.0 or higher, there are two(?) lines you need to change in the web.config file in the dashboard folder. I have edited my answer to include the modifications.

Comment: Well, i changed the web.config file, but i still get the same error message. Restart the IIS did not helpt, too. :/

Comment: Ok, now it finally works. The problem was, that iis 7.5 was not installed properly. Somehow IIs8.0 express was installed :/ After Changing that, the rest worked without any problems.